# Joining two files in AWK - Join Column at different positions

Tags: awk

File A has following 3 columns:
AccountNumber, CustomerName, Balance

File B has the following 5 columns
SystemID, AccountNumber, Product, OpeningDate

I am using the AWK code below to join the two files. It is not working

```
FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}$2 in a{ print $0, a[$1]}
```

The combined output of both the files is expected as below
SystemID, AccountNumber, Product, OpeningDate,CustomerName, Balance

Request help in AWK Code only. Am aware that similar functionality is available through SORT and JOIN but am looking for AWK solution only.

```
File A:
+---------------+---------------+----------+
| AccountNumber |  CustomerName |  Balance |
+---------------+---------------+----------+
|             3 | C             |      100 |
|             4 | A             |      200 |
|             5 | B             |      300 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+

File B:
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+
|  SystemID |  AccountNumber |  Product |  OpeningDate |
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+
|         1 |              6 | RD       | 12-05-17     |
|         2 |              4 | SB       | 15-05-17     |
|         3 |              3 | TD       | 02-04-17     |
|         4 |              5 | SB       | 15-01-17     |
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+

Output after joining:
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|  SystemID |  AccountNumber |  Product |  OpeningDate | CustomerName | Balance |
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|         2 |              4 | SB       | 15-05-17     | A            |     200 |
|         3 |              3 | TD       | 02-04-17     | C            |     100 |
|         4 |              5 | SB       | 15-01-17     | B            |     300 |
+-----------+----------------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please post a sample input. Also in `print $0, a[$1]` here the index should be `$2`?

Comment: Updated with sample input.

Comment: @user1955215: Why do you want to use `awk` for this? Is the file present with the `|`, `-----------` and `+` symbols? You want awk to de-limit on these characters? Formatting an output that way is not straight forward in awk

Comment: You want `a[$2]` in the second loop to refer to the second field. Voting to close as trivial typo.

Comment: ... though in addition, you will want to capture only `$2` and `$3` instead of all of `$0` in the first loop to get precisely the output you are looking for.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. Unable to understand the a[$2] array. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: If you are completely unfamiliar with Awk, maybe you should not insist on an Awk solution?  The key to the array is the second field.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the hint. Will it explore it further and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove pipe,plus and - symbol below is the solution -

```
cat file1
1 6 RD 12-05-17
2 4 SB 15-05-17
3 3 TD 02-04-17
4 5 SB 15-01-17

cat file2
3 C 100
4 A 200
5 B 300

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2FS$3;next} $2 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' file2 file1
2 4 SB 15-05-17 A 200
3 3 TD 02-04-17 C 100
4 5 SB 15-01-17 B 300
```

Comment: `^1` nice presentation vipin, happy to see you are learning and helping others too